# SlickGrid in Custom Formatter Function find out if row selected?

Tags: slickgrid

Been trying and searching for this one and it's the last piece I need to unlock and my SlickGrid will be complete.

Basically I'm using a custom formatter on a column and inside of the formatter I just create  an HTML link which is blue. If the row is selected (CheckBoxSelectionPlugin) I want it to match the link to be the color white. So I'd just use a different class inside that formatter instead of the class `mp_dcp_import_blue_link`. Anyone know how I can efficiently find out if the cell/row is selected?

Here is my simple formatter:

```
function PersonSearchFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return "<div class='mp_dcp_cell_grid_pad'><a class='mp_dcp_import_blue_link       mp_dcp_font' title='Launch Patient Chart' onClick='javascript:APPLINK(0,\"Powerchart.exe\",\"/PERSONID=" + dataContext['MATCH_PERSON_ID'] + "\")'>" + value + "</a>&nbsp;</div>";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think this would be easier to just handle in the css than the formatter, assuming you are using the CheckBox plugin demoed [here](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html) which adds the `selected` class to rows that are selected:

```
.selected .mp_dcp_import_blue_link{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It seems all of my css combinations to take a crack at that failed. Yours was simple and it worked perfect.